# How do I write plural with (s) for "Ice creams" for Chocolate, Vanilla and Strawberry if the user wants more than 1 of the 3 choices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my code is display plural (s) for "Ice creams" if I have more than 1 icecream flavor.
Example: Chocolate and Vanilla Ice creams. or Chocolate, Vanilla and Strawberry Ice creams.

All I get is singular and im new to Python programming after completing first chapter on Codecademy.

Here is my code below, it doesn't display Icecream nor even ice creams at the end of my flavor choices.

```
# First Name
company_name = "Dan's Icecream"

# Greetings
greeting_introduction = "\nHello! Welcome to "

print(greeting_introduction + company_name + "!")

first_name = input("\nCan I start off with your first name?\n\n")

print("\nThank you" + " " + first_name + "!")

# Various Icecream flavors
menu_item1 = "Chocolate\n"
menu_item2 = "Vanilla\n"
menu_item3 = "Strawberry\n\n"

order = input("\nWhat flavors would you like on your icecream today?\n\n" + menu_item1 + 
menu_item2 + menu_item3)

if order == menu_item1:
    print("menu_item1" + "Icecream")
if order == menu_item2:
    print("menu_item2" + "Icecream")
if order == menu_item3:
    print("Strawberry" + "Icecream")
if order == menu_item1 + menu_item2:
    print("menu_item1" + "and" + "menu_item2" + "Ice creams")
if order == menu_item1 + menu_item3:
    print("menu_item1" + "and" + "menu_item3" + "Ice creams")
if order == menu_item2 + menu_item3:
    print("menu_item2" + "and" + "menu_item3" + "Ice creams")
if order == menu_item1 + menu_item2 + menu_item3:
    print("menu_item1" + "menu_item2" + "and" + "menu_item3" "Ice creams")

order = input("\nYou said that you want " + order + "," + " is that right?\n\n")
```

Comment: What exactly is the user expected to type? They have to type the full name of the flavour... without mistakes? How should they enter multiple flavours? How should they separate multiple flavours? Shouldn't the user be told how to input this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by defining a boolean variable — one named `plural` for instance — and setting its value depending on how many items were ordered and then using it when to determine whether to add a `"s"` character to the end when print things out. The code below shows how that could be done.

It also fixes the problem with nothing being printed, which was because your `menu_item`s had a trailing `"\n"` character in them, so they never matched what the user typed in. Note also that multiple flavors will need to be separated by a space character when entered.

```
# First Name
company_name = "Dan's Icecream"

# Greetings
greeting_introduction = "\nHello! Welcome to "

print(greeting_introduction + company_name + "!")

first_name = input("\nCan I start off with your first name?\n\n")

print("\nThank you" + " " + first_name + "!")

# Various Icecream flavors
menu_item1 = "Chocolate"
menu_item2 = "Vanilla"
menu_item3 = "Strawberry"

order = input("\nWhat flavors would you like on your icecream today?\n\n" +
              "\n".join([menu_item1, menu_item2, menu_item3]) + "\n\n")

order = order.lower().split()  # Convert input to list of flavors.
plural = 's' if len(order) > 1 else ''
print(" and ".join(order) + " Icecream" + plural)

order = input("\nYou said that you want " + ", ".join(order) + "," + " is that right?\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are defining the items with "\n" like this:

```
menu_item1 = "Chocolate\n"
menu_item2 = "Vanilla\n"
menu_item3 = "Strawberry\n\n"
```

You can use .rstrip("\n") in the if so you can reformat this:

```
if order == (menu_item1.rstrip("\n") + menu_item2.rstrip("\n")):
 print("menu_item1" + "and" + "menu_item2" + "Ice creams")
```

Also please note that for getting this to work the response from user should be without space:

```
e.g. VanillaChocolate
```

So you might consider that

Comment: I think you meant to do something else than this: `"menu_item1" + "and" + "menu_item2" + "Ice creams"`, as you can create the string directly. If you wanted to interpolate the values then you feed to convert it to a format string or remove the quotations from the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the input. When you ask the user for input, and he/she enters a ice cream flavor, for example, chocolate, your program wants you to enter `Chocolate\n` which would be impossible in a terminal. So, your `if` statements return `false`.

Instead, use the code below, with comments.

```
# First Name
company_name = "Dan's Icecream"

# Greetings
greeting_introduction = "\nHello! Welcome to "

print(greeting_introduction + company_name + "!")

first_name = input("\nCan I start off with your first name?\n\n")

print("\nThank you" + " " + first_name + "!")

# Various Icecream flavors
menu_item1 = "Chocolate"
menu_item2 = "Vanilla"
menu_item3 = "Strawberry" #remove the newlines

order = input("\nWhat flavors would you like on your icecream today?\n\n" + menu_item1 + ', ' +
menu_item2 + ', '+ menu_item3 + '\n')

#I have indented the if statements so that this is easier to read
if order.lower() == menu_item1.lower(): # if the the order (all lowercase) is equal to the menu item (lowered) then pass the if statement
   print("menu_item1" + "Icecream")
if order.lower() == menu_item2.lower():
   print("menu_item2" + "Icecream")
if order.lower() == menu_item3.lower():
   print("Strawberry" + "Icecream") 
if order.lower() == menu_item1.lower() + "," + menu_item2.lower(): # comma-separated format for the input
   print("menu_item1" + "and" + menu_item2 + "Ice creams")
if order.lower() == menu_item1.lower() + "," + menu_item3.lower():
   print("menu_item1" + "and" + "menu_item3" + "Ice creams")
if order.lower() == menu_item2.lower() + "," + menu_item3.lower():
   print("menu_item2" + "and" + "menu_item3" + "Ice creams")
if order.lower() == menu_item1.lower() + "," + menu_item2.lower() + "," + menu_item3.lower():
   print("menu_item1" + "menu_item2" + "and" + "menu_item3" "Ice creams")

order = input("\nYou said that you want " + order + "," + " is that right?\n\n")
```

If this answer solved your problem, please mark as correct! Thanks...

Comment: I'd suggest calling the `lower()` method before the if-statements. Not only is it much unnecessary noise and lower readability, it will also recompute the method for the same string several times.